# How do you share changes without committing them to source control in TFS?

Tags: c#, tfs

I've made quite a few changes in my C# program on one page. I don't want to check it in right now, because it might be really messy.

What I'd like to do is save those changes so my boss can see AND INCORPORATE in the existing checked in page before it's checked in.

Is this possible in TFS?

Comment: Yes. Are you using Git or TFVC?

Comment: I suppose TFVC - VS2013 Ultimate - have not heard of TFVC

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Git, the proper approach is to create a branch, do your work in that branch, and then open a [pull request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-requests?view=azure-devops).

If you're using TFVC, you can create a [shelveset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/suspend-your-work-manage-your-shelvesets?view=azure-devops) and use a [Code Review](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/get-code-reviewed-vs?view=azure-devops).

Comment: So, you're saying, that if I Shelve my version of the page, my boss can then use Code Review to check it out?
What menu item is this (code review)?

Comment: You shelve it, then open a code review with your boss as the reviewer.

Comment: wow - you're fast -- i had to edit my question:
What menu item is this (code review)?

Comment: @Augustwind Please refer to the Code Review documentation.